# List the modified files in intellij or perforce through command line

Tags: shell, android-studio, intellij-idea, command-line, perforce

I need to write a script the lists the modified files within an intellij project, this project uses perforce as VCS.

Is there an IDEA feature accessible from command line that can do this job?
Otherwise how can I list all the modified files within a project using the p4 command?

Comment: Just run an external script?

Comment: Yes Im am writing an external script to list the unsubmitted modified files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you need is [p4 opened](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_opened.html).

IntelliJ IDEA's version control integration features are not accessible through command line, and even if they were, it would still be much faster to query the version control system directly.

Comment: True but if you could use the IntelliJ api to see modified files, it could be Agnostic to the particular VCS and work with git, svn, perforce... you could always write your own plugin making use of the OpenAPI?

Comment: Yes, you can write a plugin that will expose IntelliJ's VCS APIs as a command-line tool. It would still be much faster to query the version control system directly.

Comment: @yole p4 opened seems to list all modified files in all directories, is it possible to filter on the project directory?

Comment: Provide a path: `p4 opened path/...`

Comment: @SamStafford is there a way to get the results in local path format?

Comment: Tagged output (`-Ztag`) might provide it -- otherwise try `p4 fstat -Ro`.  Use the -F flag to format the output: https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting